# DB Mirroring in async/High Performance mode: Available in SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition?

Tags: sql-server

This should be easy, but the MS docs are not clear.

The docs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx

Indicate that in Standard edition, the only supported mirroring is "safety full only"

Taken together with this document:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191456(v=sql.105).aspx

The answer would seem to be:

> In SQL Server 2008, async, high performance mirroring is only available in Enterprise Edition

Correct?

Comment: What, in any of these docs, leads you to believe this is available in standard edition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first document you list, it is clearly stated that Asynchronous Mirroring is only supported in the Enterprise Edition of SQL Server 2008.

Synchronous Mirroring is available in the Standard Edition.

Comment: In the first document it says "Asynchronous database mirroring is supported only by SQL Server 2005 Enterprise Edition SP1 and later versions." The document is for SQL 2008, so you kind of have to assume the story for SQL 2008.

Comment: Not when the document is titled "Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2008"